# Angular1 can not load local file

Tags: angularjs, frontend

Using yeoman generator to write angular, when i add an `menu.json` in app directory. And try to use the service to get json file. It appears 404 errror.

```
angular.module('mealApp')
  .service('foodFinder', function () {
    // AngularJS will instantiate a singleton by calling "new" on this function
      this.getMenu = function() {
        return $.get('menu.json');
      }

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `menu.json` in app folder I can know its location is same as `index.html`.

How about `$.get('index.html');`

By Default yeoman generator when you use its command (Ex: grunt server) to start server it will auto host a server (Ex: http://localhost:9000) and auto load your index.html in app folder.

if you cannot it means you are using another way to start server and lost relative path.

Maybe you need to find your relative path to your menu.json (Ex: `app/menu.json` or something)